# JQueryMobile: Dropdown menus in Header

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-mobile, drop-down-menu

I am creating a JQM webapp and need to add dropdown menu to the header to achieve the following effect

```
----------------------------------
 [Menu1]   Page Title     [Menu2]     
----------------------------------
```

Any examples of dropdown widgets for JQM?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nirmaljpatel/nQTTC/) with the code I wrote for this.

[image: Screenshot from JSFiddle]

Comment: tried this on 1.7.1 and it doesn't work... formatting just doesn't come together at all... was displaying it on a droid (LG Thrill).

Comment: Works fine in both Stock browser and Chrome on my Galaxy S CM9 .

Answer (score 6):

In JQuery Mobile 1.3 there is a built in sample for this problem.

http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0/docs/widgets/popup/

```
<a href="#popupMenu" data-rel="popup" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-transition="slidedown" data-icon="gear" data-theme="e">Actions...</a>
 <div data-role="popup" id="popupMenu" data-theme="d">
    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" style="min-width:210px;" data-theme="d">
        <li data-role="divider" data-theme="e">Choose an action</li>
        <li><a href="#">View details</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Edit</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Disable</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Delete</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aVkgp/) for a sample based on jQuery Mobile's built-in select menus. I've had to do something like this in the past... it's far from perfect and likely wont render correctly on all devices, but it worked OK in my case.

[image]

Comment: Main reason I cannot use a select control is that I have to maintain a static label for the Menu name. With a select control; the text in the button keeps updating to currently selected option.

Comment: Ok. You should add that to your question so others can take that into account. You can also override the select action with jQuery so the text displayed in the drop down does not actually change.

Answer (score 4):

The jQuery Mobile 1.2 docs give an example of using the popup widget for creating a menu from a button rather than a select:

http://jquerymobile.com/branches/popup-widget/docs/pages/popup/index.html

```
<a href="#popupMenu" data-rel="popup" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-transition="fade">Menu</a>

<div data-role="popup" id="popupMenu" data-overlay-theme="b">
    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" style="width:180px;" data-theme="b">
        <li><a data-rel="popup" href="#popupMenuLevel1">Add</a></li>
        <li><a data-rel="popup" href="#popupMenuLevel1">Edit</a></li>
        <li><a data-rel="popup" href="#popupMenuLevel1">Manage</a></li>
        <li><a data-rel="popup" href="#popupMenuLevel1">Delete</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div data-role="popup" id="popupMenuLevel1" data-overlay-theme="b">
    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" style="width:180px;" data-theme="b">
    <li><a data-rel="popup" href="#popupMenuLevel2">Remove</a></li>
    <li><a data-rel="popup" href="#popupMenuLevel2">Undo</a></li>
    <li><a data-rel="popup" href="#popupMenuLevel2">Splice</a></li>
    <li><a data-rel="popup" href="#popupMenuLevel2">Reticulate</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div data-role="popup" id="popupMenuLevel2" data-overlay-theme="b">
    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" style="width:180px;" data-theme="b">
        <li><a href="index.html">Basics</a></li>
        <li><a href="options.html">Options</a></li>
        <li><a href="methods.html">Methods</a></li>
        <li><a href="events.html">Events</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a branch. It is not included in the jquery mobile releases. If you attempt to use any of the above, you will need to have the jquery and jquery mobile javascript libraries from the popup-widget branch.

Comment: @Mervyn Thank you, wonder why it is not stated in docs that this is a branch?

Comment: This works in 1.2 as released right now. Just tried it. No branch needed.  Above comment is no longer relevant.

Answer (score 0):

You should set navbar grid menu with for example 5 buttons in header bar and then set for each of navbar buttons one popup menu with dropdown transation.